# Using OneToOneField with multiple versions of data

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to have two versions of the same model while still benefiting from OneToOneField's reverse relation.

For example, let's say that I have the following models:

```python
class Company(models.Model):
    exists = models.BooleanField()

class ExtraInforation(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company)
    wealthy = models.BooleanField()
```

At this point my code uses the brilliance of the OneToOneField reverse relation, doing `company.extrainformation`calls all over the place.

Then I get a new requirement: we can't trust the `ExtraInformation` without verifying it first! Pfft, any company could claim that it's wealty...

Any changes to `ExtraInformation` need to be confirmed before publishing. Let's say that the company isn't wealthy when it registers and that information gets confirmed. Later the company wants to mark itself wealthy. At that point there needs to be the confirmed/public version of `ExtraInformation` and the unconfirmed version that needs to be confirmed.

**I want to be able to still keep those handy OneToOneField reverse relation calls but also have another version of the same data.** The problem is, of course, that there can be only one row with reference to this company in the OneToOneField.

Currently my solution is to create a new table:

```python
class ExtraInforationUnconfirmed(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company)
    wealthy = models.BooleanField()
```

Once the information is confirmed, the fields are copied from `ExtraInforationUnconfirmed` to `ExtraInformation`. This solution isn't very DRY or clean.

*What would be the best way to solve this issue?*

I studied proxy models and model inheritance. The best alternative way I could think of is to have a base model and inherit two models that have both have OneToOneField relation of their own to `Company`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean feild to the model and change it to true when confirmed:

```
class ExtraInforation(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company)
    wealthy = models.BooleanField()
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**UPDATE**
Based on your comment I suggest a version filed which can be a simple integer or a datetime. I would avoid creating two models at any cost :)

```
class ExtraInforation(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='extrainformations')
    wealthy = models.BooleanField()
    # version = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    version = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You can add a property to `Company` that returns the last extrainformation so that `company.extrainformation` will still work:

```
@property
def extrainformation(self):
    return self.extrainformations.order_by("-version").first()
```

Comment: Okay sorry, I failed to list an essential requirement: both versions must be able to exist at the same time. First the company may not be wealthy and that information gets confirmed. Later, when the company decides that it's wealthy. Then there needs to be the confirmed version that's shown publicly and the unconfirmed version that needs to be confirmed.

Comment: Property for company, that's it! Thank you. I knew I failed to think of some dead-simple solution. Actually, I'll need properties `extrainformation` (the confirmed version) and `extrainformationunconfirmed` for my scheme to work like I want it to. I'll use the `confirmed` a boolean to choose between the two.

Comment: Minor annoyance about this solution: usage of the `company.extrainformation` changes slightly. Since it's property it's always defined. Instead of checking if `extrainformation` is `undefined` I have to check for `None`.

Comment: Yes, I don't see a way around that.